# Partially infer generic index type from arguments

Tags: typescript

I have created this helper function:

```js
export function createStyleUtilForProp<TProps, K extends keyof TProps>(
  prop: K,
  style: ((val: TProps[K]) => RNStyle) | RNStyle,
) {
  return (props: TProps) => {
    if (typeof style === 'function') {
      return style(props[prop]);
    }
    return props[prop] ? style : null;
  }
}
```

And I want to use it as follows:

```
type Props = {
  border?: number;
  color?: string,
}

const getBorderStyle = createStyleUtilForProp<Props>('border', (border) => ({
  borderWidth: border,
  borderColor: '#000000',
}));
```

---

However, this throws the following error:
`TS2558: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.`

And the only way to fix it is by adding the type of the index prop:

```
const getBorderStyle = createStyleUtilForProp<Props, 'border'>('border', ...);
```

I don't like having to put `'border'` twice. Is there any way TS can infer the index type from the arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial inference is not supported in typescript up at least 3.3 (the next version at the time of writing.

There is a proposal to allow partial inference planned for 3.4 (as detailed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349)), but it has slipped back since at least 3.1 so when it makes it in is uncertain. With this proposal you might be able to write (I say might as I am speculating based on the behavior described in the issue);

```
const getBorderStyle = createStyleUtilForProp<Props, _>('border', (border) => ({
    borderWidth: border,
    borderColor: '#000000',
}));
```

Until partial inference is supported the usual workaround in such cases is to use a function that returns a function. On the first call you specify `T` and on the second one the compiler infers `K`:

```
export function createStyleUtilForProp<TProps>() {

    return function <K extends keyof TProps>(
        prop: K,
        style: ((val: TProps[K]) => RNStyle) | RNStyle,
    ) {
        return (props: TProps) => {
            if (typeof style === 'function') {
                return style(props[prop]);
            }
            return props[prop] ? style : null;
        }
    }
}
type Props = {
    border?: number;
    color?: string,
}

const getBorderStyle = createStyleUtilForProp<Props>()('border', (border) => ({
    borderWidth: border,
    borderColor: '#000000',
}));
```